# CAT & ILS Bonds/funds

Tags: mutual-funds, bonds, portfolio, historical-data, diversification

I'm constructing an portfolio with the objective to diversify as much as possible.

I would like to include securities that are uncorrelated with the financial markets.

The last few days I've been trying to find data on Insurance Linked Securities(ILS) and Catastrophe Bonds(CAT Bonds) with no success. I've looked at investing, yahoo finance and Morningstar.

Alternatively, im looking for a fund that invests mainly in ILS and/or CAT Bonds.

Does anyone know where I can find weekly data on things like this?

One example of a fund is(but I cant find historical returns on it):
•   Pioneer ILS Interval Fund

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insurance bonds can be bought from re-insurance companies by accredited investors. Also, wealth-management brokers put accredited investors into all kinds of partnerships.

The only possibility of an insurance bond fund is a closed-end fund that doesn't face redemption requests. But the Pioneer ILS fund only sells to investment advisers at a $1 million minimum and directly from the distributor at NAV. Then there are limited share repurchase offers available. So while the fund has a ticker symbol it doesn't really seem to trade on the stock market. The fund averages about 4.5% gain per year but the assets-under-management can have big changes.

An average investor can buy stock or options in re-insurance companies. Both Swiss RE and SCOR SE have good dividends and relatively stable results.

Comment: To be fair to the OP's goals - buying stock in companies that issue ILS bonds is not  the same as investing in the bonds themselves (which may not be possible for a retail investor).

Comment: The re-insurance companies both hold insurance positions and issue insurance bonds. And the insurance positions that they hold is their biggest business.

Comment: Is there forexample no ETF or anything of that nature that tracks the movements of the underling CAT/ILS? Also, thank you for your answers!

Comment: There is a Swiss Re Global Cat Bond Index.

Comment: Okey, but this index is just an index right? Its not something retail investors can invest in right?

Comment: An investment bank could issue an ETN on the index without actually holding the index but I don't know of any ETN's on this index. Wikipedia lists 17 companies or funds that invest in ILS but they appear to be for institutional or accredited investors. Call in to your broker and ask about the Pioneer ILS fund.